# PHP: a slash becomes a "V" when converted to array

Tags: php, arrays, json, encode

I have this variable : `$link = $rows['link'];` which contains a URL.
When I echo this everything is fine. eg.:

> https://www.ted.com/talks/margaret_heffernan_why_it_s_time_to_forget_the_pecking_order_at_workhttps://www.ted.com/talks/simon_sinek_why_good_leaders_make_you_feel_safehttps://www.ted.com/talks/regina_hartley_why_the_best_hire_might_not_have_the_perfect_resumehttps://www.ted.com/talks/sheryl_sandberg_why_we_have_too_few_women_leadershttps://www.ted.com/talks/roselinde_torres_what_it_takes_to_be_a_great_leaderhttps://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307

Then I would like to save this URL in an array with the following code : `$result['video'][] = array('id' => $id, 'link' => $link);`

The problem here is that the slashes become "V"'s. Eg.:`echo json_encode($result);` gives me :

> {"video":[{"id":"1","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/margaret_heffernan_why_it_s_time_to_forget_the_pecking_order_at_work"},{"id":"2","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/simon_sinek_why_good_leaders_make_you_feel_safe"},{"id":"3","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/regina_hartley_why_the_best_hire_might_not_have_the_perfect_resume"},{"id":"4","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/sheryl_sandberg_why_we_have_too_few_women_leaders"},{"id":"5","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/roselinde_torres_what_it_takes_to_be_a_great_leader"},{"id":"6","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307"},{"id":"7","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307"},{"id":"8","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307"},{"id":"9","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307"},{"id":"10","link":"https://www.ted.com/talks/stanley_mcchrystal#t-319307"}]}

Anyone who knows why it does that?

Thanks !! :)

Comment: I don't understand why this is a problem, you json encode them and they become escaped slashes `\/` and then when you decode them back the become normal again

Comment: I think that's just escaped slashes isn't it? I can't see any in your quote block, but they're \ followed by / so look like V but are actually \/

Comment: this is not "V" it is "\/" (i.e `front slash` followed by `backslash` ) for (escaping front slash).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve this by

```
json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Thanks !! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem, when you encode any string having "/" json automatically adds a reverse-solidus character "\" and the final string becomes something like "\ /".It's perfectly legal JSON. "\ /" will automatically convert to "/" when you will unserializing the string. Why worry about it, if the output is unserialized by a proper JSON parser?

If you insist on having "\ /" in your output you can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` flag while printing.
something like : `json_encode($eg_url, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);`

```
<?php
/*
 * @author Saurabh Pandey
 * Escaping the reverse-solidus character ("/", slash) is optional in JSON.
 *
 * This can be controlled with the JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES flag constant in PHP.
 *
 */    

$eg_url = 'http://www.trillbit.com/';

echo json_encode($eg_url), "<br>";

echo json_encode($eg_url, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES), "<br>";
```

output :

```
http:\/\/www.trillbit.com\/
http://www.trillbit.com/
```